# Simple Emacs keybindings

Tags: emacs, buffer, customization, key-bindings

I have two operations that I do all the time in Emacs:

1. Create a new buffer and paste the clipboard. <kbd>C-S-n</kbd>
2. Close the current buffer. <kbd>C-S-w</kbd>
3. Switch to the last viewed buffer. <kbd>C-TAB</kbd>

I feel like a keyboard acrobat when doing the first two operations.  I think it would be worth trying some custom key bindings and macros.

A few questions about this customization:

1. How would I make a macro for #1?
2. Are these good key bindings? (I know this is a bit subjective, but they might be used by something popular that I don't use.)
3. Has anyone found a <kbd>C-TAB</kbd> macro that will act like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Linux/Windows?  Specifically, I want to have a stack of buffers according to the last viewed timestamp (most recent on top).  I want to continue cycling through the stack until I let go of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.  When the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is released, I want the current buffer to get an updated position on the stack.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using vertically or horizontally split windows for this (via <kbd>C-x 3</kbd> or <kbd>C-x 2</kbd>)? It seems like it would give you fewer steps - even if you implement something like you're talking about.

I find split windows really speed up copy and pasting operations. I use the arrow keys on my num pad to switch among windows (`windmove-left`/`-right`/`-up`/`-down`), so it's only one key to press and you go to the window you want.

I guess this is a little different from what you're asking for, but it sounds like it might help speed things along a bit.

<kbd>C-x left</kbd> and <kbd>C-x right</kbd> cycle through buffers, but you have to hit it multiple times, you can't just keep the key pressed down.

---

For creating a macro for #1, you just start a macro, hit the keys you usually do to create a new buffer, and stop the macro.

So it would be something like:

<kbd>C-x (</kbd> <kbd>C-x b</kbd> `NEW` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>C-x )</kbd>

You can then save `NEW` to a file once you're done pasting, so you can use the macro again to create a new buffer. <kbd>C-x e</kbd> to try out the macro. If it works you can save it into your `init.el` file. This is done with:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `name-last-kbd-macro`

Then you'll get a prompt to enter the name of your choice. This is only good for the current session. Then you save the named macro to your initialization file. First you open your `.emacs` or `init.el` file. Then you place point where you want the macro definition to go, then you type:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-kbd-macro`

Now you can run your macro using its name via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `<macroname>` . You can bind your macro to keys too (in your `.emacs` or `init.el` file):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") '<macroname>)
```

For example this is how your `init.el` would look after creating a macro that opens a new buffer called `NEW` that is not associated with a file and binding this macro to <kbd>C-c n</kbd>:

```
;; Creates a new unassociated buffer called NEW
(fset 'new-buffer "\C-xbNEW\C-m");
;; Shortcut for new-buffer
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c n") 'new-buffer)
```

You can also throw in the paste, buffer close, and buffer switching operations. I guess you'd have to save the buffer to a file manually.

**Some resources**

- Information about [macros](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros) on EmacsWiki
- Possibly useful: [Swap text between buffers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Swapping-Text.html#Swapping-Text)

Answer (score 1):

1. start by invoking **start-kbd-macro**, finish by with **end-kbd-macro**. Afterwards you may immediately test the new macro with **call-last-kbd-macro**. If you're happy with the result you might want to [save the macro](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacrosTricks#toc5).
2. Emacs generally doesn't use C-S keybindings and they are easy to use, so I'd call them good. They might cause problems if you're using the terminal version of Emacs, but I assume that's not the case with you.
3. I use this simple snippet:

   (global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>") 'bury-buffer)

bury-buffer basically makes the current buffer the last in the buffer-list so you'll be able to cycle buffers in a predictable order.

Answer (score 1):

1. I wouldn't make a macro for that but write a function like someone else posted on this page.  Instead of `(cua-paste nil)` you could also use `(yank)`.  I'm not sure which one's better and why.
2. I don't like them that much.  For things that I use often I'd like to do as little finger acrobatics as possible, so that would mean modifier+key instead of modifier1+modifier2+key.. or use a function key if you don't feel tied to the homerow.
3. no comment